# MySQL delete lines that contains specific word

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete lines in specific column from all rows that contains specific words.

For example:

Remove lines that contain word `apple` and it is always at the beginning of the line.

```
+--+------------------+
|ID|data              |
+--+------------------+
|1 |sometext1         |
|  |sometext2         |
|  |apple sometext3   |
|  |sometext4         |
+--+------------------+
|2 |apple sometext5   |
|  |sometext6         |
+--+------------------+
```

so the result would be:

```
+--+------------------+
|ID|data              |
+--+------------------+
|1 |sometext1         |
|  |sometext2         |
|  |sometext4         |
+--+------------------+
|2 |sometext6         |
+--+------------------+
```

'SometextX' is different in every line, number of lines is different in every row and it has different number of characters in every line.
I really need this in MySQL any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess i didn't put my question right, i need to delete only part of the field  DATA just like on example

Comment: What you really need here is regex replacement, but MySQL does not natively support this.  Your options include using a UDF of some kind, or doing the replacement outside of MySQL.

Comment: **There is no native regex replacement** so I suggest a specific workaround for this question as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) to select the right rows and to update with new data as follows:

```
UPDATE `yourTable` SET `yourField` = REPLACE(yourField, 'apple', '') WHERE yourField LIKE '%apple%'
```

Comment: What happens if `apple` is part of a larger string which should not be replaced?

Comment: In the solution above the string 'apple' is searched only at the beginning of the string, as you required. The entire rest of the string, minus the leftmost X charachters (the length of the word you want to replace), is used as replacement, so no other part of the string contained in the field is touched.

Comment: I'm sorry... I interpreted 'lines' as records.
To do what you want use the REPLACE('strWhere','strWhat','strSubst') mysql function like this: 
UPDATE yourTable SET yourField = REPLACE(yourField, 'apple', '') WHERE FIELD LIKE '%apple%'

Comment: My point is just that replacing `apple` may not be safe, if `apple` could appear as part of a large word.  Not likely for `apple`, but easily possible for other words.  The OP needs regex replacement which sadly MySQL does not support out of the box.

Comment: Maybe you can use spaces to treat only single words which are not part of other longer strings ( “ apple “ ), and treat the two other possibilities in two other queries ( “ apple” at the end of the string, and “apple “ at the beginning).

Comment: Yes, you might be able to do this, but it gets very ugly, very quickly, this is why a regex engine is a good choice for such a replacement.

Comment: I agree, but as you don't have Regex replacement in MySQL... Exporting data to another environment is also error prone, so maybe remaining in MySQL is a better choice, eventually preparing and using a Stored procedure...

Comment: All valid points...actually the better thing would be to scrub the data _before_ even bringing it into MySQL.  Once the cat is out of the bag, be prepared for fur balls.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete the whole row, you can run these 3 queries in this order

```
update your_table set text=replace(text,substring(text,@start:=locate('\napple',text),locate('\n',text,@start+1)-@start+1),'');
update your_table set text=if((@start:=locate('apple',text))=1,replace(text,substring(text,@start,locate('\n',text,@start+1)-@start+1),''),text);
update your_table set text=if((@start:=locate('apple',text))=1,replace(text,substring(text,locate('apple',text)),''),text);
```

update #1 will remove apple *in the middle* of the text (prefixed by `\n`)
update #2 will remove apple *at the beginning* of its row (nothing before) and having following rows
update #3 will remove remaining cases

Comment: This solution has a problem because some of your replacements would target `apple` when appearing as part of a larger string.

Comment: "apple sometext" will be removed. What is a "larger string" ?

Comment: `grapple` for inatance.  You would remove the `apple` substring.  We really need regex replacement here.

Comment: **There is no native regex replacement** so what we need is a working workaround. I've edited the statement so `grapple` is not targeted anymore, and I have tested it. Have you tested your `DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE text REGEXP '^apple'` solution ?

Comment: Your code is complex and probably prone to error.  I vote for either uaing a regex replace UDF or doing the cleanup entirely outside of MySQL.

Comment: Your regex replace UDF would be much more complex and prone to error than this *working* code, not even mentioning the portability, so who would want to do that...

Comment: As for my original answer, the OP changed the question, or what we all thought was the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `where`:

```
where textcol not like 'apple%' or textcol is null
```

This can be part of a `select` or a `delete` (the question mentions "result" which suggests the former and "delete" which suggests the latter).  It is not clear whether you actually want to change the data or whether you just want the result set without these words.

Note:  you can do this without `or` and still handle `NULL` values, because MySQL has a `NULL`-safe equality operator:

```
where not left(textcol, 5) <=> 'apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using `REGEXP` here to match patterns in each line:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE text REGEXP '^apple';
```

`REGEXP` allows for fairly complex regex matching, and would be useful if your requirement changes or gets more complex later on.

**Edit:** MySQL has no built in support for regex replacement, so there is no easy way to accomplish what you want.

A general regex pattern to remove the word `apple` would be `\bapple\b`.  You may search on this pattern and replace with empty string.

Comment: Thanks, if i manage to export and edit my data in some tool what would regex code look like?

Comment: this will delete the whole rows